# Regex in R (str_detect)

Tags: regex, r, stringr

What must be a painfully obvious error for an expert: how do I match the location of the *bracket digit* pattern in the following strings with `stringr`?

```
library(stringr)

s <- c("ser ser (1 ( asd",
       "ser (3 (. asd",
       "ser ser (1 (2 asd")
```

I want to match the pattern "(", then any digit. I think the right regex is `"\(\d"` but this command

```
str_detect(s[1], "\(\d")
```

provides

```
Error: '\(' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\("
```

What's the right way to write this regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape slashes in R strings

```
str_detect(s[1], "\\(\\d")
```